# What is the danger of biasing the sampling when using Monte carlo in protein/peptide structure prediction

Tags: proteins, protein-structure, protein-folding

I am reading [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2001037019301540) in the link.

In introduction, paragraph 3, the last few lines are as follows

> In theory, MC methods can be as ac-
> curate as MD methods, but MC may suffer from lower efﬁciency when
> using ﬁne-grained representation of the system, especially with large
> number of explicit solvent molecules. There is also a danger of biasing
> the sampling when using MC.

What does it mean danger of biasing the sampling when using MC. Is MC not reliable in protein/peptide structure prediction?